# Python NLTK Inaugural Text Corpora hands-on solution needed

Tags: python, nltk, nltk-book, katacoda

I am doing a course in NLTK Python which has a hands-on problem(on Katacoda) on "Text Corpora" and it is not accepting my solution mentioned below. Have been stuck on this problem since long. Need to complete this hands-on to proceed foreword in course.

**Problem definition:**

> Import inaugural corpus For each of the inaugural address text
>   available in the corpus, perform the following. Convert all words into
>   lower case. Then determine the number of words starting with america
>   or citizen.
>
> *Hint : Compute conditional frequency distribution, where condition is the year in which the inaugural address was delivered and event is
>   either america or citizen. Store the conditional frequency
>   distribution in variable ac_cfd.*
>
> Print the frequency of words ['america', 'citizen'] in year [1841,
>   1993].
>
> *Hint: Make use of tabulate method associated with a conditional frequency distribution.*

For this I have written below solution:

```
ac_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((target, fileid[:4]) 
for fileid in inaugural.fileids() 
for w in inaugural.words(fileid) 
for target in ['america', 'citizen'] 
if w.lower().startswith(target))
ac_cfd.tabulate(conditions=['america', 'citizen'], samples=['1841', '1993'])
```

which gives output:

```
          1841 1993 
american     7   14  
citizen     38    2
```

I was nto able to find same problem on different forums, though I did found a similar problem which wanted to plot the conditional frequency distribution, their solution was same as mine with one different, instead of tabulate line they had plot. (https://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html)
But Katacoda isn't accepting this solution and I am not able to proceed foreward in the course as completing hands-on is mandatory.
Please Help

Comment: What's the link to the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. It works for me on Katacoda. In question it is asking for the words starting with america and citizens hence I sliced the words to 7 characters.

```
import nltk

from nltk.corpus import inaugural

ac_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist([(fileid[:4],word.lower()[:7]) 
                                   for fileid in inaugural.fileids() 
                                   for word in inaugural.words(fileid)
                                  ])

print(ac_cfd.tabulate(conditions =['1841', '1993'],  samples=['america', 'citizen'] ))



   america citizen 
1841       7      38    
1993      33       2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ac_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
    [(fileid[:4], target) for fileid in inaugural.fileids() for w in inaugural.words(fileid) for target in
     ['america', 'citizen'] if w.lower().startswith(target)])

ac_cfd.tabulate(conditions=['1841', '1993'], samples=['america', 'citizen'])
```

Question was to Print the frequency of words ['america', 'citizen'] in year [1841, 1993] but you where doing the reverse hence Its not getting accepted.